# Display values order by year and using bootstrap tab and show content content year in each tab

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I want to show bootstrap nav-pills/ tab to show data.
On tab header, year should `br` visible and on click each year, and it's respecting content shoild be visible.

How to write query for this in Laravel controller.

My MySQL table : `placement`

```
id | name | company | year | status
```

`blade file` :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link  @if($loop->first)
        active  
     @endif" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true"> Year </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade @if($loop->first)
        show active
     @endif" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">

Year wise content from database.

</div>
  </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/

**`Controller.php` :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Placements;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class placementController extends Controller
{
    public function mech()
    {
        
       
       
        $users = Placements::where('dept','mechanical')->Paginate(30);

        $archive = Placements::orderBy('year', 'desc')
        ->whereNotNull('year')
        ->get();
        

        $nonteach = Placements::where('dept','mechanical')->where('status', '=', 1)->cursorPaginate(30);
        
        return view('mech/mechanical-engineering-placement')->with('users', $users)->with('archive', $archive);


       
       

    }
```

2022 | 2021 |

below content for 2022

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] good question

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
$archive = Placements::orderBy('year', 'desc')
        ->whereNotNull('year')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function(Placements $post) {
            
            return ($post->year);
        })
        ->map(function ($item) {
            return $item
                ->sortByDesc('year')
                ->groupBy( function ( $item ) {
                    return ($item->year);
                });
        });

 return view('mech/placement')->with('archive', $archive);
```

Above code in controller will bring certain field in row as array.

```
{
    "2022": {
        "2022": [
            {
                "id": 2304,
                "name": "KEE S",
                "company": "Jay Jay Mills India Pvt Ltd"
            }
        ]
    },
    "2021": {
        "2021": [
            {
                "id": 2304,
                "name": "kerthaS",
                "company": "Jay Jay Mills India Pvt Ltd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```